# Can we use Primary keys as normal column?

Tags: oracle

Can we use Primary Keys as "normal columns" in Oracle? 
I am trying to do the following query but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT DATA_1,DATA_2 FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MY_TABLE_PK=10;
```

I have an **Invalid identifier error:**

```
 SQL Error: ORA-00904: "MY_TABLE_PK": invalid identifier
```

How can we read the Primary Key value in those cases?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: What is your issue? Define "Doesn't work"

Comment: Then MY_TABLE_PK is possibly the name of your primary key INDEX and not the name of your primary key COLUMN. You can only select columns in your query, not indexes themselves. Post your table structure (or index create statement) for more help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your primary key INDEX is based upon a primary key COLUMN in your table as are all [constraints](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm).

You can select the primary key COLUMN but the INDEX is a seperate object in the database and cannot itself be selected (you would not want to anyhow). In your case, the primary key constraint itself is probably enforcing uniqueness in the primary key column(s) as well as decreasing search time by using an index.

I think you might be getting slightly confused in your terminology.

Query the `user_ind_columns` dictionary view to find the primary key column the index is based upon if you are unsure:

```
SELECT *
  FROM user_ind_columns
 WHERE index_name = 'MY_TABLE_PK';
```

Then add the underlying COLUMN(S) (there might be more than one) to your select query to have it returned.

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

A primary key is a normal column and yes you can just select or use the column in the where clause.

In you SQL, you are selecting DATA_1 twice - do you have a column in the table called MY_TABLE_PK ?

The name given to the primary key is shown in explain plans but the data you select will be the column name, not the primary key name.

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE supplier
(   supplier_id     numeric(10)     not null,
    supplier_name   varchar2(50)    not null,
    contact_name    varchar2(50),   
    CONSTRAINT supplier_pk PRIMARY KEY (supplier_id)
);
```

The primary key here is called supplier_pk and is using the the column supplied_id so we can do a select like this

```
SELECT supplier_name from supplier where supplier_id=1234;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that MY_TABLE's primary key is MY_TABLE_PK.  If so, the query you posted never reads that column.  Try changing  your query to

```
SELECT MY_TABLE_PK, DATA_1
  FROM MY_TABLE
  WHERE MY_TABLE_PK = 10
```

This assumes there's a row where MY_TABLE_PK contains 10.

Share and enjoy.